Actually proving CW pairs have the homotopy extension property
If $(X,A)$ is a CW pair then $X\times \{0\}A\times I$ is a deformation retract of $X\times I$ (which is equivalent to the H.E.P)
I am just looking to understand the idea here, so not a lot of details are given. The proof is quite known.
Hatcher claims  that if we look the $n$-skeleton we have
$$X^n\times I=(X^n\times\{0\}\cup(X^{n-1}\cup A^n)\times I)\cup_{f}D^n\times I$$
where $f: \left( D^n \times \{0\} \cup \partial D^n \times I \right) \to X^n \times \{0\} \cup \left( X^{n-1} \cup A^n \right) \times I.$
Now performing a deformation retraction of $D^n\times I$ to $D^n\times\{0\}\cup \partial D^n \times I $
gives the space: $$(X^n\times\{0\}\cup(X^{n-1}\cup A^n)\times I)\cup_{f}D^n\times\{0\}\cup \partial D^n \times I$$
but since we identify with $f$ the above space is just $(X^n\times\{0\}\cup(X^{n-1}\cup A^n)\times I)$ ?
Then I don't understand how after that we get $X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I.$
The author writes: "If we perform the deformation retraction of $ X^n \times I$ onto
$X^n \times \{0\} \cup (X^{n-1} \cup A^n) \times I$
during the  t-interval $[1/2^{n+1}, 1/2^n]$, this infinite concatenation of homotopies is a deformation retraction of $X \times I$ onto
$X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I.$"
I have to idea what that means.

What exactly is unclear? I see no issue with Hatcher's statement. Please be more precise in identifying what you're confused about.

@BenSteffan What we mean by "If we perform the deformation retraction of $ X^n \times I$ onto
$X^n \times {0} \cup (X^{n-1} \cup A^n) \times I$
during the  t-interval $[1/2^{n+1}, 1/2^n]$" ?

I don't think Hatcher claims what you say he claims. The scenario you are describing is one in which there is only one $n$-cell in $X-A$.

@Thorgott I am just trying to prove/explain the gaps of the claims Hatcher makes. You can look at Prop 0.16 the book is online.

Yes, I'm pointing out that you've made a minor error in summarizing Hatcher's argument. He talks about copies (plural) of $D^n\times I$ attached along $D^n\times{0}\cup\partial D^n\times I$, but you are only talking about a single copy.

@Thorgott I think it's irrelevant I just took the case where we obtain the space by a single copy, the proof remains the same for arbitrary copies.

Hatcher's argument "If we perform the deformation retraction of $ X^n \times I$ onto
$X^n \times {0} \cup (X^{n-1} \cup A^n) \times I$ during the  t-interval $[1/2^{n+1}, 1/2^n]$, this infinite concatenation of homotopies is a deformation retraction of $X \times I$ onto $X \times {0} \cup A \times I$" does not work. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4818927/349785.

@PaulFrost Thank you so much Paul!
